# To use Gitlab Dashboards - How to use grafonnet with jsonnet to produce a json file that I can use with Grafana

Tags: gitlab, grafana, jsonnet

Can someone please show me how to use the jsonnet files with grafonnet? Like a step by step for newbies?

I want to use the GitLab dashboards here in my local Grafana environment - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/runbooks/-/tree/master/dashboards

The only somewhat useful tutorial I have found so far is here - https://hodari.be/posts/2020_06_27_grafana_and_grafonnet_dashboards/

I assume that jsonnet will spit out json that I can import into my Grafana.

So I downloaded the jsonnet file that I would assume let me use a kubernetes version dashboard and tried to run the jsonnet on it -

```
$ jsonnet kubernetes_version.dashboard.jsonnet
RUNTIME ERROR: couldn't open import "grafana/basic.libsonnet": no match locally or in the Jsonnet library paths.
    kubernetes_version.dashboard.jsonnet:8:15-47    thunk <basic>
    kubernetes_version.dashboard.jsonnet:90:1-6
```

I did a search all over the net for grafana/basic.libsonnet and I can not find anything.

Can some one give a step by step of what is needed to do in order to convert a jsonnet file to a usable json - or am I understanding this totally wrong??

I did look at the jsonnet and grafonnet home pages and it didn't help me at all.

Where do I get and put grafana/basic.libsonnet?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to point `jsonnet-bundler` to the folder where the project's own `jsonnetfile.json` file resides, to let it *also* download further dependences.
Then specify the needed `vendor/`-ed folder locations, below runs ok, showing a JSON dashboard to stdout:

```
$ jb init

$ jb install gitlab.com/gitlab-com/runbooks
GET https://github.com/grafana/grafonnet-lib/archive/3082bfca110166cd69533fa3c0875fdb1b68c329.tar.gz 200
GET https://github.com/grafana/jsonnet-libs/archive/8df6a4ff1623781260c3236761c2ebe837958b3f.tar.gz 200
GET https://github.com/jsonnet-libs/xtd/archive/e9ffe67357685703df80703844885da91d59296e.tar.gz 200
GET https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/archive/dd0f1df93645a917b32c0fa7bfdc331730dc64a2.tar.gz 200
GET https://github.com/yugui/jsonnetunit/archive/6927c58cae7624a00f368b977ccc477d4f74071f.tar.gz 200

$ jsonnet -J vendor -J vendor/gitlab.com/gitlab-com/runbooks/libsonnet vendor/gitlab.com/gitlab-com/runbooks/dashboards/general/kubernetes_version.dashboard.jsonnet
[JSON output ...]
```

--jjo